# How to install SSL certificate text on Ubuntu nginx

Tags: ssl, nginx

I am running a Ubuntu 18.04 server on AWS Lightsail, using nginx.  I have a purchased SSL certificate for my domain name through the domain registrar (domain.com) - I can download the 'certificate' and the 'key' as long strings of text characters/symbols.  How do I then 'install' this SSL certificate onto my Nginx server?

Comment: You will have to upload the certificate files to the relevant location on the server then configure nginx. You might find this link useful to explain how to do this http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two files that must be configured on the Nginx server, the certificate `.crt` and the certificate key `.key`, you simply have to have these 2 files on your Nginx server.

And using a `server` block which are Nginx configuration files, located in the path `/etc/nginx/sites-available`, in your `server` block you must write the 2 lines that refer to your certificate and key.

Inside the `server` block you must have:

```
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nameofkey.key;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nameofcertificate.crt;
```

Where in each line you specify the path of the files.